# How to set jQuery dialog's titlebar's background color?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui-dialog

My page has 2 `jQuery dialogs`. When page is generated both `<div>` elements have the same `class` definitions:

```
<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
    <span class="ui-dialog-title" id="ui-dialog-title-dvMonitor">Monitor Status</span>
</div>

<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
    <span class="ui-dialog-title" id="ui-dialog-title-selectMsg">Error</span>
</div>
```

I need to set the 2nd dialog's title's background to red. This dialog will show "Error" message as specified in the `span` element of the second `<div>`.

I also added logic in my `.js` file on a failed condition:

`$('#ui-dialog-title-selectMsg').parent('.ui-dialog-titlebar').css('background-color', 'red');`

But I still have the following popup:

[image]

How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Add an `error` class on the **div** for the second dialog box. Then in your stylesheet write the following.

```
.error { 
  background: red;
}
```

You can change the color from `red` to a nicer color using hexadecimal codes. **Example**:

```
.error {
  background: #EC485B;
}
```

That will give you more of a brick red. Play around with hexadecimal color codes to find the ride shade of red for your application.

Comment: Can I just add `style="background:red"` to the second dialog box?

Comment: Just did that and background of the dialog itself turned red

Comment: @gene You can do that, but that's not best practice. You should be writing your CSS in a separate file. Ignore the people that say do it with jQuery. Using javascript for styles will be too expensive in the long run, and it's a bad habit. It will make your site slow.

Comment: Ah just re-read and realized you said title. Add the class to the span.

Comment: When adding specifying styles for the second span `ui-dialog-title-selectMsg`, it only sets background to `Error` text. It does not set background for the whole title bar, but that's what I need

Answer (score 0):

I recommend CSS solution for this -

1. You can add style to ui-dialog-title-selectMsg

   ```
   #ui-dialog-title-selectMsg {
      background: red;
   }
   ```
2. Or you can use css pseudo class

   ```
   .ui-dialog-titlebar:nth-child(2) > .ui-dialog-title {
       background: red;
   }
   ```

I assumed you wanted to give background color to span.

If you want to give background color to title bar div, use the below CSS:

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar:nth-child(2){
        background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do this with jquery use the below syntax,

```
$('#ui-dialog-title-selectMsg').parent('.ui-dialog-titlebar').css('background-color','red')
```

or if you wnat to user inline then add

```
 <div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix" style="background:red">
        <span class="ui-dialog-title" id="ui-dialog-title-selectMsg">Error</span>
</div>
```

or you add an class for second dialog says 'err-bg' and then give style to it.

```
.err-bg{
background: red;
}
```

Avoid the inline css as much as possible. because it's not recommended

Comment: I tried to insert the syntax into my .`js` file, but the dialog still does not have `red` title. Look at picture I added in my question description

Comment: $('#ui-dialog-title-selectMsg').parent('.ui-dialog-titlebar').css('background','none'). Use this  and then $('#ui-dialog-title-selectMsg').parent('.ui-dialog-titlebar').css('background-color','red') @gene

Comment: as soon as I added the first line when setting background to none, I start getting a javascript error saying that my function where I define all the code is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
#ui-dialog-title-selectMsg {
  color: red;
}
```

into your stylesheet. 
If you want to use a different color, you can use http://www.colorpicker.com/ and copy the hexadecimal code of the color and simply add as followings (notice the hashtag):

```
#ui-dialog-title-selectMsg {
  color: #E0412F;
}
```